# Чиптюнинг или чип-тюнинг?

Tags: орфография

Интересует вопрос, как правильно пишется: чиптюнинг или чип-тюнинг?

Answer (score 2):

В данный момент слово почти не фиксируется печатными источниками (гугл находит пару руководств и журналов, с разнобоем в написании). Будем исходить из того, что по внешним признакам слово имеет право на жизнь: его составные части "чип" (кристалл микросхемы) и "тюнинг" (настройка) прижились в языке как слова. Общий смысл: настройка ("тюнинг") параметров механизма (напр. в автомобиле) путём программирования ("прошивкой чипа" памяти). Поскольку запись в два слова (как в английском) была бы в русском бессвязным набором двух существительных, остаётся записать сложное слово без соединительной гласной и сделать выбор: с дефисом или слитно. По Розенталю, ***сложные существительные без соединительной гласной***, обозначающие названия механизмов, а также научные, **технические**, общественно-политические **термины** пишутся через **дефис**. http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=45 Отсюда обоснованным выглядит дефисное написание *технического термина* "**чип-тюнинг**", поскольку он составлен из частей, которые в русском закрепились как отдельные слова (ср. с жутковатыми "коворкинг", "каршеринг", где отдельные части самостоятельно не используются, а их смысл выявляется лишь этимологическим разбором).